# Confusion at 'apt-get dist-upgrade' definition

Tags: apt, dependencies

According to `man apt-get`:

> upgrade "is used to install the newest versions of all packages currently installed".
>
> dist-upgrade "in addition to performing the function of upgrade, also intelligently handles changing dependencies with new versions of packages"

I searched for several definitions of dist-upgrade on the Internet and I found that it is used when new dependencies (not already installed) have to be installed, although that is not what `man apt-get` definition says, as I understand.

I always find man pages to be very precise, but I don't understand what 'changing dependencies with new versions of packages' exactly means in the dist-upgrade definition. Does it mean that dependencies are changed for new versions of the same dependencies? Does 'changed' mean that one dependency is removed and another one installed, or simply that a new version of the same dependency is now installed and used instead of the version replaced? Doesn't upgrade already install new versions of dependencies and 'tell somehow' that the package must use this new dependencies?

Supposing that package A depends upon a file X inside a package B (the dependency): When upgrade installs a newer version of package B, called package B-2, is this newly dependency used by package A or is it that A still uses package B until dist-upgrade is executed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say prior to upgrading you have a situation like this, where both `php` and and `python` packages have a dependency on libxml-dev-1.2

```
                            +--------------------+
                            | python_3.1         |
+--------------+            |                    |
| php7.0       |            | depends on libxml-dev_1.2
|              |            +-----+--------------+
| depends on libxml-dev_1.2       |
|              |                  v
+------------+-+
             |              +---------------------+
             |              | libxml-dev-1.2      |
             +------------> |                     |
                            |                     |
                            |                     |
                            +---------------------+
```

you then update `apt`'s local index , with `apt-get update`,
now the `apt-cache policy` shows there is a new package version available for php - version `7.3`.
But running `apt-cache show php` shows that the new php package needs a newer version of its libxml-dev dependency, the new php package needs say, `libxml-dev-1.3`.
Normally apt would install all dependencies necessary to satisfy the php 7.3 install or upgrade, however if apt replaced `libxml-dev-1.2` with the newer `libxml-dev-1.3` (remembering that having `libxml-dev-1.2` and `libxml-dev-1.3` running side by side is not really an option) in order to satisfy the `php7.3` dependency requirements, it would "break" the python dependency requirement.
In this scenario, `apt-get upgrade` would just do nothing, however if you look at the `man apt-get` entry for `dist-upgrade`

> dist-upgrade
>   dist-upgrade in addition to performing the function of upgrade,
>   also intelligently handles changing dependencies with new versions
>   of packages; apt-get has a "smart" conflict resolution system, and
>   it will attempt to upgrade the most important packages at the
>   expense of less important ones if necessary. The dist-upgrade
>   command may therefore remove some packages. [...]

So `apt-get dist-upgrade` will push bend/break the rules about package specified dependencies in order to get packages upgraded.

Therefore of the two commands, `apt-get dist-upgrade` will upgrade more packages than would otherwise be upgraded with `apt-get upgrade`

Comment: Now that I understand all the background of changing dependencies, I guess that I would have to have studied how dependencies are changed by apt-get upgrade, in the first place, and I also guess that replacing '...handles changing dependencies with new versions of packages..." by "...handles changing dependencies due to new versions of packages..." would have avoided a lot of confusion.

Answer (score 0):

both case can happen depending if the dependency is over a file or a package. for that matter it exist the command deborphan that can show you if there is orphaned package because of newly installed dependancy.

I generally always use dist-upgrade, and sometime issue a `apt-get remove $(deborphan)` to clean up things.